# MySQL user year report based on join date and left date

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the MYSQL employees table like this:

| ID | name | joining_date | date_left |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 2018-01-01 | 2019-04-30 |
| 2 | DEF | 2019-01-01 | 2020-12-31 |
| 3 | GHI | 2019-01-01 | null |
| 4 | JKL | 2021-11-30 | 2022-04-02 |

And I need output in below mentioned case in one single query.

1). If I want the report of year 2018 (Here, year 2018 means start date 2018-01-01 and end date 2018-12-31)
In this case, only row with id 1 should be return

2). If I want the report of year 2019
In this case, row with id 1, 2 and 3 should be return

3). If I want the report of year 2020
In this case, row with id 2 and 3 should be return because for #3 date_left is null that means employee is not left

4). If I want the report of year 2021
In this case, row with id 3 and 4 should return because date_left is null for #3.

5). If I want the report of year 2022
In this case, row with id 3 and 4 should return because date_left is null for #3.

Can anyone please help in this MySQL query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may treat this as the overlapping range problem, between joining and leaving date range, and a range covering an entire calendar year.  For 2018, we can try:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE ('2018-01-01' <= date_left OR date_left IS NULL) AND
      '2018-12-31' >= joining_date;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22fe2682b4160f8ed7552ed643c66834) here for the 2021 calendar year.

Comment: That is correct for 2018 but it will not work for year 2019

Comment: @JaydeepRajgor ... you need to change the range to cover 2019 in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You just need to pass the desired date range to provided query! @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I have added the #4 which should show in report of year 2021 and 2022 but it will not with this query.

Comment: @JaydeepRajgor The query seems to be working q.v. [this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22fe2682b4160f8ed7552ed643c66834) for the 2021 calendar year, returning the 3rd and 4th records.